# Python: How do i get the name of the current archive?

Tags: python, zip, egg

Is there any way to get the current archive name in Python?

Something like

> EggArchive.egg
>
> Lib
> ---SomePythonFile.py

From SomePython.py, is there anyway to fetch the .egg name?

Comment: You mean, you want to discover the distribution name, or the full egg file name? Do you have the *distribution name* up front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `__file__` contains the path to the current python file. So If you have a structure:

```
.
`- your.egg
   `-your_module.py
```

And in `your_module.py` you have a function:

```
def func():
    print(__file__)
```

The the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your.egg')
from your_module import func
func()
```

Will print out:

```
/path/to/your.egg/your_module.py
```

So basically you can manipulate the `__file__` variable if you know where relatively your module is inside the `egg` file and get the full path to the `egg`.

To get the relative path to the egg in the script that's in the egg file you'll have to do:

```
def rel_to_egg(f):
    my_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(f))
    current = my_dir
    while not current.endswith('.egg'):
        current = os.path.dirname(current)
    return os.path.relpath(current, my_dir)
```

Now let's say `__file__ == '/test/my.egg/some/dir/my_script.py'`:

```
>>> print(rel_to_egg(__file__))
'../..'
```

Comment: this is good... just wondering if it is possible to retrieve relative path to this file... without using pkg_resources?

Comment: the current file... something like ..\lib\lib1\<files in this folder> ?

Comment: We misunderstood each other. So let me try again to see if I understood you correctly. 1. You have a `library.egg` that has in itself a module `my_mod` 2. Somewhere else you have a script `my_script.py` 3. In `my_script.py` you `import my_mod` from `library.egg`. 4. You want to know where is the `library.egg` relative to the `my_script.py`?

Comment: nop... 1. I have a library.egg that has in itself a module my_mod 2. i have multiple modules within the .egg. 3. I also have a script with the .egg my_script.py 4. In my_script.py I want to  import my_mod from library.egg. 5. Hence I  want to know where is the library.egg relative to the my_script.py?

Comment: How do you run the `my_script.py` when it's inside the egg?